# Is the adjective order "sunny, secret, green" correct?

Tags: adjective-order

> I went to Sarah's house, and she showed me her **sunny, secret,
>   green** yard.

I'm quite sure *green* goes at the end. And doing a search on ngram I found more results with *sunny, secret* than *secret, sunny*, so the one above should be correct. But I wanted a confirmation.

Comment: *Green* does go on the end. *Sunny* and *secret* can go in either order. And I'm not sure whether the internet results mean anything at all. You have to get rid of all the hits where *secret* is a noun.

Comment: Don't get too hung up on that [Royal Order of Adjectives](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/the-royal-order-of-adjectives/). At best it's only a *rough guide* (with plenty of exceptions). And your particular set of adjectives (which would probably never occur in *any* sequence in real life, as a "cascade" of leading adjectives) isn't one where it's really even meaningful to identify a "most likely" order.

Comment: @Peter: Surely it would depend on the *exact* context? To be honest, I can't easily imagine a context where even any *two* of the cited adjectives might be likely to appear consecutively before ***yard***, but there are lots of written instances of both [secret sunny garden](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22secret+sunny+garden%22) and [sunny secret garden](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sunny+secret+garden%22), where I'd say the difference (if any) is a matter of which adjective the writer thinks is most *closely* associated with "garden" for his specific context.

Comment: There's an interesting article about adjective order here: https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/sep/13/sentence-order-adjectives-rule-elements-of-eloquence-dictionary I was certainly one of the people who had no idea there was a rule (or, perhaps more accurately, a custom) regarding tjhis.

Comment: If you've got the commas there, the so-called "royal order" doesn't apply even inasmuch as it usually does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most usual order of adjectives is this:

1 a general opinion: exquisite, terrible
1 b specific opinion: friendly, dusty
2 size: big, small, tall
3 physical quality: thin, rough, untidy
4 shape: round, square, rectangular
5 age: young, old, youthful
6 colour: blue, red, pink
7 origin: Dutch, Japanese, Turkish
8 material: metal, wood, plastic
9 type: general-purpose, four-sided, U-shaped
10 purpose: cleaning, hammering, cooking

Thus your order would be, at first glance: secret (opinion) sunny (physical quality), green (colour) yard. However, if by 'green', you meant 'grassy', 'leafy', or 'rich in vegetation', then that would be a physical quality, and you are free to arrange adjectives within the same group in any order, so you could exchange 'sunny' and 'green'.

[Adjectives order](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order)

[The Study of Adjective Order](https://slate.com/culture/2014/08/the-study-of-adjective-order-and-gsssacpm.html)

Comment: Why is *secret* an opinion? It can be a quality (as is *sunny*). For example, you'd generally say *the small secret door* and not *the secret small door*. (For confirmation, there are lots more hits for *small secret door* than *secret small door* on Google.)